# hazelcast XA transaction support

Tags: transactions, hazelcast, xa

We are currently reviewing hazelcast for our requirements and one of requirements is to support XA across multiple HZ cache instances.

E.g.
HZ instance 1 - Account has one Map with All customer accounts

HZ instance 2 - Customer has Customer information

We can leverage local transactions when both Customer and Account are in a single HZ instance.

However, our volume of data will be in millions and therefore, we want to able to add partition members on the fly and would like to have separate Customer and Account clusters so that we can scale as needed.

Additionally, another reason we want to keep the cache's separate is so that in some other process we can have two HZ instances with Account and Position information.

Please recommend if you envision an alternative approach.

When we tried using Atomikos, the first HZ instance registers properly, however when we try to enlist the second resource, it throws a nested transaction exception.

Since we have our own wrappers on top of hazelcast code, it is not simple to share the code. I will try and work on getting a simpler sample ready.

However, at the moment I would like to understand if our approach is supported.

Comment: Hey, I'm open to you, therefore I have to say sorry but I think it will be hard to offer help on this. I see your point on scaling individually between the two different data sets but up to now I know about nobody tried to register two different HZs into one transaction. I don't think it will be easily possible to solve that in on a non-dev contract basis, especially because you already mentioned you can't easily share code. On development consulting we can have a NDA to solve this issue. We can try but I doubt it'll work otherwise.

Comment: PS: If you want to try solving this on community level please add as much information (version HZ, Atomikos) and source as possible.
PPS: dev support here means POC support :)